# C# Property SetValue cannot handle generic List type

Tags: c#, winforms, generics, system.reflection, setvalue

In my WinForm application, I'm actually using the `LightweightDAL` project which provide a nice method to fill up my datamodel. All works fine except for a properties set as List of another model. This is my model class:

```
public class SchedaFamiglia
{
    [DBField("Id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DBField("IdFamiglia")]
    public int IdFamiglia { get; set; }

    [DBField("IdMamma")]
    public int IdMamma { get; set; }

    [DBField("IdPapa")]
    public int IdPapa { get; set; }

    [DBField("IdBambino")]
    public List<SchedaBambino> Figli { get; set; }

    public SchedaFamiglia()
    {
    }}
```

The model `SchedaBambino` above, is just a list of base type properties (int32, string...).

And this is the snippet of `GetItemFromReader` method:

```
private static T GetItemFromReader<T>(IDataReader rdr) where T : class
    {
        Type type = typeof(T);
        T item = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
        PropertyInfo[] properties = type.GetProperties();

        foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
        {
            // for each property declared in the type provided check if the property is
            // decorated with the DBField attribute
            if (Attribute.IsDefined(property, typeof(DBFieldAttribute)))
            {
                DBFieldAttribute attrib = (DBFieldAttribute)Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(property, typeof(DBFieldAttribute));

                if (Convert.IsDBNull(rdr[attrib.FieldName])) // data in database is null, so do not set the value of the property
                    continue;

                if (property.PropertyType == rdr[attrib.FieldName].GetType()) // if the property and database field are the same
                    property.SetValue(item, rdr[attrib.FieldName], null); // set the value of property
                else
                {
                    // change the type of the data in table to that of property and set the value of the property
                    property.SetValue(item, Convert.ChangeType(rdr[attrib.FieldName], property.PropertyType), null);
                }
            }
        }
```

The method above unfortunately can't handle List of generic and I've no idea how to implement.

Someone could help me?

Comment: What do you mean the method "can't handle List of generic"? (what you have is also not the entire method?)

Comment: Why is the `item` variable useful? Edit: Sorry, do you want to `return item;`

Comment: Basically I cannot fill the property "Figli" as List<T> of datamodel SchedaBambino. Seems that method handle only basic data type, not collections. I'm trying to find out how to handle also collections.

Comment: @Ras, how in your `IDataReader` is stored `SchedaFamiglia` objects,  
concretely the `List<SchedaBambino> Figli`?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan: interesting question! I will check, because I guess I can fill the main model and the collection (List<SchedaBambino>) separately

Comment: @Ras: please be careful with terminology. Collections != generics, it's actually the exact opposite.

Comment: @Ras - how do you expect your List items to be stored in the database? Do you have a separate FigliTable? What should be stored in SchedaFamiglia?